# What difference does the backslash make in the below syntax to remove a UNIX directory having contents?

Tags: shell, unix, delete-file, rm, rmdir

I need to delete a directory that contains several sub-directories and files. After googling and looking at the man pages of `rmdir` and `rm`, I have these two alternatives:

`$ rm -rf <folder_name>` and `$ \rm -rf <folder_name>`

How do these two differ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using **\** implies that you want your shell to **ignore** any aliases based on this command

Let's say you have an alias like this one:

```
alias rm='rm -i'
```

You would very much like to ignore it if you want to rm your whole **/**.

Good luck

Comment: You're welcome! This one has made my life much easier more than once..!

Comment: Thanks! didn't know about [alias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28command%29#Overriding_aliases)..

Comment: getting into the backslash using habit is too easy, I try not to use this approach and when I am 100% I want to get rid of a bunch of files, I user the command from its original source instead of pointed by an alias, as in "/bin/rm -r /some/directory/location"

Comment: @silencedhaven Didn't get how using the command from its original source helps as a replacement to overriding the alias..